# UICollectionView cell individual height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollextionView` and It currently works out the height for a `UILabel`. Each label has its own height. I would now like to do the same for the collection view cell. I only seem to be able to change them all to the same. What should I do? Thanks

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ChatCellCollectionViewCell


    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    cell.textLabel.text = "\(messageArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.nameLabel.text = "\(namesArray[indexPath.row])"


    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    frame = cell.textLabel.frame
    cell.textLabel.sizeToFit()
    frame.size.height = cell.textLabel.frame.size.height
    cell.textLabel.frame = frame


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Flow Layout, the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol has a function named `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` which will allow you to do this.

Comment: Where should I use this line? Instead of `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` or inside that code above?

Comment: You can do this in the same view controller that implements `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, although you'll need to declare support for `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in that class' `@implementation`

Comment: So should I use that as well as or instead of `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: You'll want to use both – `cellForItemAtIndexPath` provides the cells, and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` provides the corresponding size.

It might be worth reading through Apple's Collection View Programming guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the UICollectionViewFlowlayout, see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html

Scroll to Specifying the Size of Items in the Flow Layout

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your view Controller

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGFloat width=0.0;
CGFloat height=0.0;

if (IS_IPHONE_5){
    width=90;
    height=120;
}else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
    width=107;
    height=130;

}else if (IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS){
    width=125;
    height=150;

}else{
    width=90;
    height=120;

}

return CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

}

In the place of Device Detection You can use indexPath.row ..like

```
if (indexPath.row==0){
  // Your Code
  }
```

**Note** : It returns CGSize..

I hope this answer is helpful for you.

Comment: This is working however I need to get the height of the cell from the content. Is there any way to give a temporary value and adjust it once the content is set out.

Comment: OK now you can add the cell size = Your content.frame.size.height

Comment: Do I add this in the code above or where I set the cell's content?

Comment: This link make helpful for you..http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/08/variable-sized-items-in-uicollectionview/  Your Website is very nice..